# Java type casting / narrowing of primitive variable

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types

I'm getting exponential value in the result of expression where I'm adding double with long.

```
package com.testing;

import java.util.Date;

public class TypeCasting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long varA = 100000;
        long varB = 3000000;

        double logVarA = Math.log10(varA);      //  5.0
        double logVarB = Math.log10(varB);      // 6.477121254719663

        long timeStampInSec = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
        System.out.println(timeStampInSec);     // 1552543503

        double totalValue = logVarA + logVarB + timeStampInSec;
        System.out.println(totalValue);         // 1.5525435144771214E9

        double finalScoreDampingFactor = 1000;

        double finalScore = totalValue / finalScoreDampingFactor;
        System.out.println(finalScore);         // 1552543.5144771214   
    }

}
```

In **totalValue** variable why I'm getting **1.5525435144771214E9** value and when I'm deviding it with 1000, getting **1552543.5144771214**.

Can any body please explain ?

Comment: What did you expect it to output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation `EX` means "times 10 to the power of X".

So the original number was `1552543514.4771214`.

Answer (score 1):

A number has the same value, regardless of how it's represented.  What you see printed as a String is just a representation of the number.

The JVM has decided, for whichever reason, that the number should be printed in exponential form.  If you want to force it to print it differently, you can use [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

```
double totalValue = logVarA + logVarB + timeStampInSec;
System.out.printf("%f%n", totalValue);         // 1552547672.477121
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.5525435144771214E9**
is **1552543514....** divided by 1000 is **1552543....**

Is it possible that you misinterpreted the **1.5525435144771214E9** ?